# Series Crystal Oscillator Amplitude Control

Tags: rf, analog, bjt, oscillator, radio

I need a 24 mhz clean sine wave.

I made an oscillator like this and it works, but the bottom of my waveform is clipping. I tried a variable 1k resistor on the output to gnd and can shrink the amplitude a bit, however oscillation stops if the waveform gets small enough to be clean.

Is there a way to reduce the amplitude of the oscillator output so it no longer clips?
[image: Schematic]

Comment: If that circuit works at all it's just by chance.  Typical practice is to build a good oscillator, putting stress on getting the frequency stable -- then if you need a pure sine wave output, follow it with a filter.  I'd use a 24MHz oscillator can followed by an LC filter, or I'd pull a circuit out of the ARRL Handbook or a radio frequency circuits book and follow _that_ with an LC filter.

Comment: @TimWescott The plan is to filter and buffer the output...This seems to be a common crystal oscillator topology, if you google "Pierce oscillator/Series crystal oscillator" something very similar comes up, which is odd. I actually wonder how something like this would not clip, all I see is a positive feedback loop through the crystal. Maybe I biased things wrong?

Comment: If you're going to roll your own oscillator circuit, then yes, this is a way to do it.  You're depending on the parasitic capacitance in the transistor to make it work, though.  And yes, you can, to some extent, control clipping by biasing the transistor less (reduce the value of the 5.1k resistor.  But doing _that_ increases the risk that the oscillation won't start.

Comment: @TimWescott Thanks for the insight, I think I'll just use a colpitts oscillator instead. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, it answered my question.